# SQL Query to find the uid of the person with max(status_count+follower_count) and whose is_my_friend = 1

Tags: sql

I have created a table with the following structure-

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE followers
    (
     uid int UNSIGNED NOT NULL UNIQUE,
     PRIMARY KEY(uid),
     follower_count int UNSIGNED ,
     is_my_friend bool,
     status_count int UNSIGNED,
     location varchar(50)
    )";
```

I need to find the uid of the person with max(status_count+follower_count) and whose is_my_friend = 1

I wrote the following query but I ain't getting the correct uid.

```
SELECT p.uid FROM (select uid,is_my_friend,max(follower_count+status_count) from followers) p WHERE p.is_my_friend = 1;
```

Comment: What if there is more than one user with the same maximum?

Comment: @Mark: its okay...my code can deal with that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following query will work:

```
Select uid
From followers
Where is_my_friend = 1
Order By (follower_count+status_count) desc LIMIT 0,1
```

Limit 0,1 works in MySql.

Or, if you want to return all rows where follower_count+status_count = max only, this is the query:

```
Select uid
From followers
Where is_my_friend = 1
  And (follower_count+status_count) = (select max(follower_count+status_count)
                                       from followers
                                       where is_my_friend = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SECLECT uid FROM followers ORDER BY (follower_count + status_count) DESC WHERE is_my_friend = 1
```

Comment: @Svisstack: SELECT uid FROM followers WHERE is_my_friend = 1  ORDER BY (follower_count + status_count) DESC

Answer (score 1):

> SELECT top 1 uid
>   (follower_count+status_count)
>   as totalcount FROM  followers WHERE
>   p.is_my_friend = 1 order by totalcount desc

I am not 100% if that order by is possible. Try it out, if not create a view that combines those fields